# A USB to VGA or DVI adapter with support for Windows 7 Aero?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, dvi, vga, aero

I'm looking to add a 3rd monitor to my setup via a USB-to-DVI/VGA adapter. My 3rd monitor is an old VGA one just 1280x1024, so resolution doesn't seem to be an issue, but almost every USB-to-DVI/VGA adapter I looked at has some review that explicitly states that Aero will be completely disabled when the adapter is in use.

Does anyone know of an adapter that they know does support Aero fully under Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this online post](http://en.akihabaranews.com/17016/pc/a-new-usb-to-dvi-dongle-with-aero-interface-support) talking about one which supports Aero, though it doesn't support Direct3D or OpenGL on the display attached to it. Alternately, have you considered a [Matrox DualHead2Go adapter](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/) or something similar? You would need to have 2 monitors with the same resolution, but I think it would still work with aero, since it just presents one super-wide display to windows, then splits it.